# Change WooCommerce Registration Error Message

Tags: wordpress, filter, woocommerce

I would like to change the WooCommerce registration error message that appears if an email address is already registered.

To make it safe for updates I execute this code (not working code) in my child functions.php

```
function ra_change_error_messages( $errors, $username, $email ) {

    if ( email_exists( $email ) ) {
        return new WP_Error( 'registration-error-email-exists', __( 'sdfhasd il address. Please log in.', 'woocommerce' ) );
    }

}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_registration_errors', 'ra_change_error_messages', 10, 3 );
```

The value I am trying to filter can be found here on line 95: http://hookr.io/plugins/woocommerce/3.0.6/files/includes-wc-user-functions/

Please note: I know it would be possible to modify the file includes-wc-user-functions.php . But that would not be update-proof.

Thank you! :)

Comment: is your code throwing errors? Being yes or no, always better to be more precise what behaviour it creates instead of "Not working". What i would try would be to put `var_dump($errors)` in your function and produce your "existing mail error" to see what's inside. Then try to modify it in your filter function, or return a similar structured output.

Comment: Hey @Kaddath : Thanks for your comment. It's basically doing nothing. It's just ignoring my code. When I use var_dump($errors) I don't see any changes in behavior of the site.

Comment: `var_dump` is handy, but will print things in "the place thay are called", most of the times in the raw HTML, and can be hidden by overlays and such, but if the file is called by ajax, you will only see it in the ajax call result (network tab in your browser tools). You can echo another value like "blablablah" just before to help you find it with a search in source code.

Comment: @Kaddath : if I echo "bla" right before the var_dump() still nothing is visible, also in the source code. Funny thing is, that another filter in this functions.php is working perfectly.

Comment: you have 2 options then, it's in an ajax reponse, or your function is never executed.. unfortunately, i found no way to search in all responses in one go, and i am in a bit of hurry right now..

Comment: Thank you for help. I guess the filter function is not executed :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this below function for change registration errors

[image]

```
function my_woocommerce_add_error( $error ) {
    return str_replace('An account is already registered with your email address. Please log in','sdfhasd il address. Please log in.',$error);    
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_error', 'my_woocommerce_add_error' );
```

Comment: Hey @Shital Marakana : Thank you, but unfortunately this doesnt work in my case. What's weird: It takes WooCommerce very long to throw the error message...

Comment: not working :( Could it be that the function is not executed? (see comments below the question)

Comment: Still, not working. It seems the filter doesn't get hooked :(

Comment: it is working in my woo commerce demo. please check upload screen shot

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150323/discussion-between-shital-marakana-and-ben-spi).

Answer (score 0):

Add add_action instead of add_filter